# How to set limits of grid in barplot?

Tags: r, grid, bar-chart, limit

I am trying to put grids in my barplots, but they appear in front of the data and not in the background. I tried to fix this using

```
panel.first = grid()
```

As for the data I am trying to plot, the first column consists of the year numbers (2014-2021) and the second columns are the corresponding values (all vector classes are numeric). When trying to plot using the following code:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

barplot(mean_trend[,2],names.arg = mean_trend[,1],col="skyblue",ylim = c(0.1,95),cex=0.8,cex.names=0.85,las=2,cex.lab=0.85,lwd=1.5,panel.first = grid())
mtext(side=2,line=2.3, "Average amount in mm", font=2, cex=0.8)
box(lwd=1.5)

barplot(freq_trend[,2],names.arg = freq_trend[,1],col="skyblue",ylim = c(2,4500),cex=0.85,cex.names=0.85,las=2,cex.lab=0.85,lwd=1.5,panel.first = grid())
box(lwd=1.5)
mtext(side=2,line=3.3, "Average flood frequency", font=2, cex=0.8)
```

I obtain the following result[image]

As you can see, the grid is now behind the plotted data, but exceeds the box/plot limits. How can I fix this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't add a data `mean_trend` - I give an example with other data.

About `add` and others arguments - you can read `?barplot`

```
# One row, two columns
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

#PLOT1
barplot(table(mtcars$cyl), main = "PLOT 1", col = c("yellow", "green", "red"), ylim = c(0, 15))
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL, lwd = 1, lty = 1, col = "gray")
barplot(table(mtcars$cyl), col = c("yellow", "green", "red"), ylim = c(0, 15), add = TRUE)
 
#PLOT2
barplot(table(mtcars$cyl), main = "PLOT 2", col = c("yellow", "green", "red"), ylim = c(0, 15))
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL, lwd = 1, lty = 1, col = "gray")
barplot(table(mtcars$cyl), col = c("yellow", "green", "red"), ylim = c(0, 15), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thank you! Just out of curiosity, what is the purpose of the last `par(mfrow=c(1,1)` ?

Comment: @LuukS Oops, forgot to delete. It is redundant. If I helped you, you can accept my answer ;)